# Command Prompt Programming batch

Tags: cmd

I want to make a batch file to ping an IP address like `1.30.200.3`:

```
Pinging 1.30.200.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=124
Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=124
Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=124
Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=124

Ping statistics for 1.30.200.3:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 28ms, Average = 27ms
```

I need to ask if the `"Received"  >= 2` type only one line like this:

```
Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=124
```

else

type how many Received and `"Failure"`

OutPut Like This
If The received more than and equal 2 packets

"Reply from 1.30.200.3: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=124"

Or if not more than and equal 2
OUTPut Like This

"Received  = 0  & Failure"

Comment: Parse `ping 1.30.200.3|find /i "packets: sent"`  command using [`FOR /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
:loop
    wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime > 2" get responsetime,timestamprecord
goto loop
```

Another example

```
wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime >= 0 and statuscode is not null" get responsetime,timestamprecord,statuscode
```

For help -

```
wmic /?
wmic path Win32_PingStatus /?
wmic path Win32_PingStatus get /?
wmic format /?
wmic append /?
```

Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for what various constants mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
call :check www.google.com
call :check www.notexist.xxx
goto :eof

:check
ping %1>ping.tmp
for /f %%i in ('type ping.tmp^|find /c "TTL="') do set count=%%i
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type ping.tmp^|find "TTL="') do set output=%%i
if %count% geq 2 (echo %output%) else (echo Received = %count% ^& Failure)
del ping.tmp
```

`TTL=` is much more reliable than `Recieved` (it's independent of the language) (and easier to parse)

Answer (score 0):

You already have other answers. Basically, this code parses the output of the `ping` command. It is hardcoded to whatever English Windows 7 outputs. This should be considered brittle as it will likely not work in other languages and possibly not with other Windows versions.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET EXITCODE=0

SET HOSTNAME=localhost
SET TEMP_FILE=%TEMP%\pingcount_!RANDOM!_!RANDOM!.tmp

ping>"%TEMP_FILE%" %HOSTNAME%
SET EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %EXITCODE% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO host %HOSTNAME% not found
    GOTO TheEnd
)

SET REP_LINE=

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%a IN (`type "%TEMP_FILE%"`) DO (
    IF "!REP_LINE!" EQU "" (SET REP_LINE=%%a)
)

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-7 delims=, " %%a IN (`FINDSTR /C:"Packets: Sent" "%TEMP_FILE%"`) DO (
    SET RCOUNT=%%g
)

IF %RCOUNT% GEQ 2 (
    ECHO %REP_LINE%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Received = %RCOUNT%, Failure
)

:TheEnd

IF EXIST "%TEMP_FILE%" (DEL "%TEMP_FILE%"
EXIT %EXITCODE%
```